# Remove Icon if there's no children in Jquery-UI Accordion

Tags: jquery, submenu, jquery-ui-accordion

I want to ask, how do you hide the icon on the accordion if there's no sub menu.

Please help. I can't find it on the documentation.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Customize icons</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var icons = {
      header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
      activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
    };
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      icons: icons
    });
    $( "#toggle" ).button().click(function() {
      if ( $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons" ) ) {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", null );
      } else {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", icons );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est. </p><p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

That's the code from the accordion jquery-ui. It's complete and what I want to ask is to disable the icon if there's no sub menu.

Comment: post the part of the code you need help with and explain which icon and submenu you are talking about

Comment: what do you mean by "submenu"?

Comment: I dont see a submenu here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zt4LF/

Comment: I think you should try to hide/show these icons manually by javascript by loop through the container and find the icon in the accordion's header `ui-accordion-header span.ui-accordion-header-icon`

Comment: Oh sorry, what I mean is the paragraph after each section. Did you see the icons on the left? the arrows?

Comment: can you give me some sample? thanks